# ¿Cómo meter variables java de JSP en la llamada a una función JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

Buenas a todos, por trabajo tengo que unir código java, html y javascript.

Tengo un JSP donde declaro la una variable que necesito usar en una Función javascript. Todo me funciona correctamente hasta que intento introducir la variable. Esta variable esta definida correctamente ya que la uso en el código java del JSP y todo va correctamente, todo entre <% %>.

```
   <%
      int variable = 5;
   %>

    <button id="btn1" type="button" onclick="copy(<%=variable%>)" data-loading-text="Cargando..."></button>
```

Así es como estoy intentándolo. Ovbiamente este no es el código, es solo un ejemplo resumido para centrarnos en lo importante, ya que todo lo demás funciona correctamente. Necesito saber, cómo meter esa variable en la funcion "copy" de tal manera que pueda usarla para lo que hay dentro de ella.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quizá esta respuesta se aleje un poco de lo que buscas, pero te recomiendo que intentes no usar NUNCA "scriptlets" de Java en ficheros JSP. En general [es una mala práctica](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files).

Mi recomendación es que guardes el valor que necesites en un input "hidden":

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="${variable}" />
```

y desde el Javascript leas y uses ese valor, algo como lo siguiente:

```js
let boton=document.getElementById('boton');
let variable=document.getElementById('variable').value;

boton.addEventListener('click', function () {
   console.log(`la variable vale ${variable}`);
});
```

```html
<input type="hidden" id="variable" value="5"/>
<button id="boton">Púlsame</button>
```

Así evitas dos cosas:

- Usar scriptlets.
- Mezclar HTML y Javascript. Lo ideal es añadir el control de eventos y todo el comportamiento en un fichero js fuera del HTML por temas de limpieza y legibilidad.

Comment: El problema es que debo usar sriptlets, es como me han ordenado hacerlo en el trabajo y me estoy devanando la cabeza. Tu solución es muy interesante. ¿Podría meter variables de java dentro de un hidden?                                      
                                                                                                                  
 Gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: Sí, pero recuerda que se guardan como texto.

Comment: <input type="hidden" id="variable" value="<%"Variable"%>"/> ¿Seria asi?

Comment: Mira la notación que he usado, con ${...}, es lo que se llama [EL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_Language)

Comment: Ah! Perfecto. ¡Muchísimas gracias!